# 2 backgrounds stretch 1 background

Tags: css

Is there a way to stretch 1 background. If you have set 2?

```css
body{

background-image: url(../images/pattern.png), url(../images/2.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
}
```

Something like stretch not the first image but the second image (2.jpg)

[image]

the image needs to be stretched 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
body {
    background-image: url(bg1.png), url(bg2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat;
}
```

bg1.png (contains a single '1') would be repeated down
bg2.png (contains a single '2') would be repeated across and down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css, you can repeat the first image down, and only have the second image being stretched to 100%

```
body {
    background-image: url(bg1.png), url(bg2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y, no-repeat;
    background-size: 29 29, 100% 100%;
}
```

[image]

There seem to be some issues in combination with DOCTYPE. The following piece of CSS is working well combined with DOCTYPE.

```
body{
    background-image: url('../images/pattern.png'), url('../images/2.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px 29px, 100% 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the two images? Not sure what is happening, so might help figuring the issue

Comment: Hope this will help https://googledrive.com/host/0B6iVF_nyNJLDdnJJOE9uSXBwWXM/index.html

Comment: If you remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` it works fine, see this image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/265253/StackOverflow/so.png